# Show the right-continuity of the distribution function (defined as a measure on Borel sets)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory, measure-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions

Consider the measure space $\big(\mathbb{R_+},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R_+}),\mu\big)$, $\; b=\mu (\mathbb{R_+})$, possibly $b=+\infty$. Also assume $\mu\big([0,t]\big)<\infty \; \; \forall t \in \mathbb{R_+}$.

Define

\begin{equation}
c(t)=\mu\big([0,t]\big), \;\; t \in \mathbb{R_+}
\end{equation}

Provided that $c$ is non-decreasing, show that $c$ is right-continuous, i.e., show that for any sequence $(t_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{R_+}$ such that $t_n \searrow t \in \mathbb{R_+}$, it holds
\begin{equation}
c(t_n) \searrow c(t)
\end{equation}

This question is taken from exercise I.5.14 of "Probability and Stochastics" by E. Cinlar.

**My attempt**

I would rely on the sequential continuity of measures, but it only holds for increasing sequences of sets if the measure $\mu$ is not finite. Precisely, I would like to write as follows:

Fix $t \in \mathbb{R_+}$ and consider any sequence $(t_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{R_+}$ decreasing to $t$. Then

\begin{equation}
t_n \searrow t \implies [0,t_n] \searrow [0,t] \implies \mu\big([0,t_n]\big) \searrow \mu\big([0,t]\big) \implies c(t_n) \searrow c(t)
\end{equation}

But in fact sequential continuity of measures is defined for increasing sequences of sets, and it can be applied to decreasing sequences of sets only when $\mu\big(\mathbb{R}\big) = b < \infty$, so that

\begin{equation}
\mu\big([0,t_n]\big) = b - \mu\big((t_n, \infty]\big) \searrow b - \mu\big((t,\infty]\big) = \mu\big([0,t]\big)
\end{equation}

because I could apply sequential continuity of $\mu$ on the increasing sequence of sets $(t_n, \infty])$ so that

\begin{equation}
\mu\big((t_n, \infty]\big) \nearrow \mu\big((t,\infty]\big)
\end{equation}

So, not only I cannot apply sequential continuity to decreasing sequences in order to get right-continuity of $c$ when $\mu\big(\mathbb{R}\big)=\infty$, but I even get left-continuity of $c$ from the sequential continuity of $\mu$ over increasing sequences of sets.

Any help in proving the right-continuity of $c$ would be much appreciated, as I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: When you write $\mu$ is a cdf, as in your title, do you mean that $\mu$ is a probability measure?

Comment: No, $\mu$ denotes a measure with no restrictions

Comment: In that case, we typically use the terminology "distribution function" of the measure $\mu$. I would reserve "cumulative distribution function" for the probability context. Nevertheless, it actually suffices to prove the claim for finite measures like I show in my answer. Hopefully it is enough to help you write down your own proof.

Comment: Ok, clear. I did not notice this distinction in my textbook, but I have fixed the title removing "cumulative".

Comment: One last comment about what's written in the post. The general theorem of the kind in the question addresses the limiting values of $\mu(C_i)$ when $C = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty C_i$ and $C_1\supset C_2\supset\dots$, or $C = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_i$ and $C_1\subset C_2\subset\dots$. We always have $\mu(C_i)\to \mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_i)$ in the latter situation (regardless of whether $\mu$ is finite). If $\mu(C_1)<\infty$, we have $\mu(C_i)\to \mu(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty C_i)$. I just wanted to clarify this point because I think the first sentence after "My attempt" is a little muddled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t_0\in\mathbb R_+$ be given, and $t_n\downarrow t_0$. Since we assume $\mu([0,t])<\infty$ for every $t$, by assumption, $\mu([0,t_0+1])<\infty$. There exists $N = N(t_0)$ such that for $n>N(t_0)$, we have $t_n<t_0+1$. Therefore, without loss of generality, we can replace $\mu$ with the restricted measure $d\mu' = 1_{[0,t_0+1]}d\mu$, where $\mu'$ is now a finite measure on $\mathbb R_+$ with $\mu'([0,s]) = \mu([0,s])$ for all $s\le t_0+1$. In particular, $\mu'([0,t_n]) = \mu([0,t_n])$ for all $n > N(t_0)$.

By what's written above, it suffices to prove the claim for the finite measure $\mu'$, which I assume you know how to handle by taking complements and using continuity from below of measures. The key to this reduction is that the continuity is a "local" statement, and the measure you are given in the assumption is "locally finite."

Comment: Many thanks you for answer, it is so much appreciated. My proof now goes as follows.

Provided that $t_n \downarrow t_0 \in \mathbb{R_+} \implies \mu'\left((t_n,+\infty]\right) \uparrow \mu'\left((t_0,+\infty]\right)$ by sequential continuity,

we have that

$\forall n \geq N \; \; \mu\left([0,t_n]\right)=\mu'\left([0,t_n]\right)=\mu'\left([0,t_0+1]\right)-\mu'\left((t_n, +\infty]\right) \uparrow \mu'\left([0,t_0+1]\right)-\mu'\left((t_0, +\infty]\right) = \mu'\left([0,t_0]\right) = \mu\left([0,t_0]\right)$


I hope it is correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fran712: It looks good. A minor comment, the last "$\uparrow$" should be a "$\downarrow$" because of the "$-$" sign. Nice work!